# Is there a way to recover a drivelock password? or reformat the drive?

Tags: hard-drive, password

One of the kids put a DRIVELOCK password on one of the hard drive laptops in our Ubuntu LAB. I tried removing the drive and reformatting it via USB to make it usable, but it doesn't even show up as a drive or partition. However it does show up as /dev/sr0 however it says there is no media detected when you try to do something to it.

Comment: /dev/sr0 is your cd/dvd drive.

Comment: Nope thats the drive.That acer aspire one does not have a CD/DVD rom drive. Once, I disconnect the USB Hard Drive /dev/sr0 disappears. SO That is definitely the drive.

Comment: Then somehow it *thinks* it's a cd instead of a hard disk, which is pretty fubar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am sorry to say that it doesn't look good. The Drive Lock password
>   protects the data on your hard drive through encryption. If your
>   computer is stolen, the data on the hard drive is inaccessible without
>   the Drive Lock password. This password can not be reset. If it is lost
>   or forgotten, the hard drive must be replaced.

<sup>Source: [geekstogo](http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/topic/124117-drive-lock-password-forgotten-and-lost/)</sup>

If the drive is password protected, you can not format or use killdisk. The firmware will not permit any access. Depending on the brand of hdd you might want to call the manufacture, and see if they can help you, or you can try HDD Wipe Tool.  Unfortunately its only available for windows, and can be downloaded [here](http://hddguru.com/software/2006.04.13-HDD-Wipe-Tool/)

You could also try booting from a Live CD like Ubuntu, and run the command below.  Make sure you choose the right drive.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/hda bs=1M
```

Comment: Thanks I gave that DD command a whirl. It says media not inserted. It's treating it like a removable drive or CD-ROM or something.

Comment: It looks like this technology is SED and compatible with the "OPAL" standards. Perhaps SEDutil could be used to speak life into the drive? (Though, obviously, by design, the _data_ previously on it will be unrecoverable...)